# How do I evaluate path expressions on python collections like I might use XPath for XML documents?

Tags: python

XML has XPath. Perl has Data::Path. Does anything exist in python to evaluate path expressions on python objects, or collections at the very least?

Consider this collection:

```
deployments = [
    {'type': 'database',
     'owner': 'fred',
     'server': 'db-F'},
    {'type': 'database',
     'owner': 'carol',
     'server': 'db-W'},
    {'type': 'application',
     'owner': 'carol',
     'server': 'web-A'},
    {'type': 'application',
     'owner': 'anthony',
     'server': 'web-A'}   ]
```

It would be helpful if I could write a "path_search" function, called like this:

```
path_search(deployments, ".//*[owner = 'carol']")
```

Which returns this:

```
[   {'type': 'database',
     'owner': 'carol',
     'server': 'db-W'},
    {'type': 'application',
     'owner': 'carol',
     'server': 'web-A'}   ]
```

The reason pathing is preferable to a hard-coded structure traversal is that my config varies in both structure and nested-ness from file to file.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the functionality you are looking for? I don't think there is a 1:1 equivalent to `Data::Path` but maybe we could look at specific scenarios.

Comment: Hmm. There are XQuery engines that can load JSON (and, as XQuery is a superset of XPath, run queries exactly like the one you propose against it), but that would mean loading your content into a database and querying it rather than keeping everything strictly in-process.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a [`dpath`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dpath) library in PyPI.

> A python library for accessing and searching dictionaries via /slashed/paths ala xpath

But the library appears to be focused in searching in nested dictionaries only.

2. There is also a [`jsonpath-rw`](https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw) library which supports a different search expression to find items.

Comment: much nicer than my answer :). I vote for this one. Thanks @memoselyk. I learned from it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)

you can use this script to convert your dict to xml, then use lxml path to search it.

```
import lxml.etree as et

def data2xml(d, name='data'):
    r = et.Element(name)
    return et.tostring(buildxml(r, d))

def buildxml(r, d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            s = et.SubElement(r, k)
            buildxml(s, v)
    elif isinstance(d, tuple) or isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            s = et.SubElement(r, 'i')
            buildxml(s, v)
    elif isinstance(d, basestring):
        r.text = d
    else:
        r.text = str(d)
    return r


deployments = [
{'type': 'database',
 'owner': 'fred',
 'server': 'db-F'},
{'type': 'database',
 'owner': 'carol',
 'server': 'db-W'},
{'type': 'application',
 'owner': 'carol',
 'server': 'web-A'},
{'type': 'application',
 'owner': 'anthony',
 'server': 'web-A'}   ]
dict_deploy=data2xml(deployment)
ret = dict_deploy.xpath(".//*[owner = 'carol']")
```

The downside is now your data is xml and you should handle it that way.

PS: code borrowed from :[here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577882-convert-a-nested-python-data-structure-to-xml/)

Comment: If you can add a method to convert an arbitrary Python dictionary (or at least one conforming to the schema implicit in the OP's example) to an lxml tree, I'd see this as a good answer. Otherwise, it strikes me as answering a different question; the OP doesn't have `<foo><bar></bar></foo>` as their input.

Comment: OMG, the question update a lot. let me try to update the answer as well

Comment: Reading the edit history, the question certainly has clarified its focus; I'm not sure it's "changed" as such -- it did, from the very beginning, say that it wanted a way to evaluate expressions *on python objects*.